# How can I link Youtube API-upload with my Website?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

this is what I want to do.
The users who log on to my website will upload videos to the website. Is there any way through which I can upload all those videos onto youtube under one-single account?? If yes, please guide me.

Comment: Unfortunately, your probably looking in the wrong place.  StackOverflow questions are best answered when dealing with a specific, absolute programming issue.  Your question is more of a request for informational resources or a tutorial.  You should read the YouTube API documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_Videos